# Phonegap returns object Object but echo correct data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phonegap

I'm making a phone app using PhoneGap with PHP on the server side. the Login function has been working fine, but AJAX returns an error [object Object] while PHP returns the correct value's in JSON.

it's for making a phone app for an existing website and using its database.
the data my PHP prints is correct yet I receive an error response from ajax.
    Alert(response)
Gives an [object Object] return value on error

whenever I try 
    alert(response.val)
I strangely get undefined, but in the network, I can see the printed data is correct in JSON.

```
 {{"user_id":"390","response":"Success"}}
```

but when I look in the console on my browser I see an unexpected error.

```
 Unexpected parameter ':'
```

my ajax function is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnLogin").click(function () {
        var gebr = $("#login_username").val().trim();
        var pass = $("#login_password").val().trim();
        var dataString = "username=" + gebr + "&password=" + pass + "&login=";
        var msg = "";
        $("#message").html("Authenticating...");

        if (gebr != "" && pass != "") {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: "json",
                //contentType: "application/javascript",
                crossDomain: true,
                url: "http://url/page/app/index.php?&jsoncallback=?",
                headers: "application/json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var user_id = response.user_id;
                    var success = response.response;
                    localStorage.setItem("user_id", user_id);
                    window.location = "home.html";
                    alert("login successfull");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    $("#message").html("error..");
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        } else {
            msg = "Please fill all fields!";
            $("#message").html(msg);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

PHP

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');


$gebruikersnaam = $_REQUEST['username'];
$wachtwoord = md5($_REQUEST['password']);
$user = [];


//if user and password are filled
if (!empty($gebruikersnaam) && isset($wachtwoord)) {
//checks if user_id has been found
if (!$found_user_id) { 
    $msg = "user not found!";
    print json_encode($msg);
} else {
    if (($gebruikersnaam == $user['gebruikersnaam'] && $wachtwoord == $user['wachtwoord']) && ((!empty($user['single_allowed_ip_address_for_login']) && $user['single_allowed_ip_address_for_login'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])|| empty($user['single_allowed_ip_address_for_login']))) {
        //responds with this data
        $user_id = $user['user_id'];
        $response[] = array(
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'response' => 'Success'
        );
        print json_encode($response);       
    } else {
        $msg = "user is incorrect";
        print json_encode($msg);
    }
  }
}
```

I have been wanting to get a successful response and saving the user_id in local storage so it can be used on a different page.

Edit:
after using console.log on the response i got an odd object.

```
​
     abort: function abort()​
     always: function always()​
     catch: function catch()​
     done: function add()​
     fail: function add()​
     getAllResponseHeaders: function getAllResponseHeaders()​
     getResponseHeader: function getResponseHeader()​
     overrideMimeType: function overrideMimeType()​
     pipe: function pipe()​
     progress: function add()​
     promise: function promise()
​
     readyState: 4
​
     setRequestHeader: function setRequestHeader()​
     state: function state()
​
     status: 200
​
     statusCode: function statusCode()
​
     statusText: "load"
​
     then: function then()​
     <prototype>: {…
```

which is strange because none of these functions are made and the only thing which i can recognize is the statuscode.

Comment: Notice your response is double wrap array, why? where are you trying to do `response.val`?

Comment: you cannot alert object type of data.  you need to use console.log() or you have to define the property of the object.. example 

    var a = [{'user1':{'id':1,'age':24},{'user2':{'id':2,'age':44} }];

you cannot `alert(a)` but you can `console.log(a)`.

you can also `alert(a.user1.age);`

if user1 does not exist in the above object you will get an error..

Comment: The JSON object " {{"user_id":"390","response":"Success"}}" is wrong. It should be like [ {"user_id":"390","response":"Success"}] or {"res":{"user_id":"390","response":"Success"}} at browser end

Comment: The double wrap array is because i made $response into an array. either way removing it or changing it to $response["response"] doesn't change the outcome. i still get an object Object error.
also after using console.log on the response i scan see that the object it returns is the entire POST. with statuscode, abort, always, catch, done, fail function (which arent even used).

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your JSON. `{{"user_id":"390","response":"Success"}}` is not valid JSON. It needs to be `{"user_id":"390","response":"Success"}`.

You're getting a strange object in your console.log because your `response` in the `error: function (response)...` is actually the `jqXHR` jQuery object and will not return your response directly in its arguments. Stick with `success: function(response)...` and output whatever your server sends back.